# How to extract JSON response value in array list?

Tags: java, json, jsonp

My json response

```json
{
    "status": {
        "status": "OK",
        "errorCode": "",
        "errorMessage": ""
    },
    "statuses": [
        {
            "ID": "Published",
            "Name": "Published"
        },
        {
            "ID": "Pending",
            "Name": "Pending"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have used below code

```
public static JsonPath rawToJson(Response r)
{ 
    String respon=r.asString();
    JsonPath x=new JsonPath(respon);
    return x;
}

JsonPath jsonres=rawToJson(res);
arrlist =jsonres.get("statuses");
```

I need to extract ID and store in array list

```
arrlist= {Published,Pending}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JsonPath rawToJson(Response r)
{ 
    String respon=r.asString();
    JSONObject jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(respon);
    JSONObject doiJsonObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("statuses");
}
```

Comment: just a small change. statuses is an array.